# textFieldShouldBeginEditing Fires on all text Fields

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement textFieldShouldBeginEditing so that I would show popup with dialog boxes for some text fields and the others would be free text.

I implemented it like that:

```
   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{


    if(textField == self.petType)
    {
        petTypePicker = CZPickerView(headerTitle: "Pet Types", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", confirmButtonTitle: "Choose")
        petTypePicker?.delegate = self
        petTypePicker?.dataSource = self
        petTypePicker?.needFooterView = true
        petTypePicker?.headerBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4509803922, green: 0.3529411765, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        petTypePicker?.confirmButtonBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4509803922, green: 0.3529411765, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        petTypePicker?.show()
        return false
    }
    else if(textField == self.petBread)
    {
        breedPicker = CZPickerView(headerTitle: "Breeds", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", confirmButtonTitle: "Choose")
        breedPicker?.headerBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4509803922, green: 0.3529411765, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        breedPicker?.confirmButtonBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4509803922, green: 0.3529411765, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        breedPicker?.delegate = self
        breedPicker?.dataSource = self
        breedPicker?.needFooterView = true
        breedPicker?.show()
        return false
    }
    else if(textField == self.petColor){
        colourPicker = CZPickerView(headerTitle: "Colours", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", confirmButtonTitle: "Choose")
        colourPicker?.headerBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4509803922, green: 0.3529411765, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        colourPicker?.confirmButtonBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4509803922, green: 0.3529411765, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 1)
        colourPicker?.delegate = self
        colourPicker?.dataSource = self
        colourPicker?.needFooterView = true
        colourPicker?.show()
        return false
    }
    else if(textField == self.petDateOfBirth){

        let currentDate = Date()

        DatePickerDialog().show(title: "DatePickerDialog", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", minimumDate: nil, maximumDate: currentDate, datePickerMode: .date) { (date) in
            if let dt = date {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

                dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

                self.petDateOfBirth.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: dt) as String)"
            }
        }

        return false
    }
    else{


        return true

    }

}
```

But for some reason this is what happens:

When the return is false, it works perfectly, when the return is true, it fires the method textFieldShouldBeginEditing for all texfields, which makes them all go into their if statements, hence firing all the dialogs.

Any Ideas why I am experiencing this behavior, please note that all the fields are inside a stack view

Thank you

Comment: try to use the instance property isFirstResponder(). Change your if statement from if textField == self.petType to if self.petType.isFirstResponder().

Comment: @webjunkie Thank you it worked !! I ANDed textField.isFirstResponder() to all conditions and it worked :) Thank you. Please add it as an answer to make it the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad it worked ;).

Use the instance property isFirstResponder() to check wether or not you have click on the correct textField. In your case modifying your if statements to `if self.petType.isFirstResponder()` will do the trick.